# Separação do texto de uma string em um array

Tags: java

Preciso de uma forma pra separa uma string como a que segue:

> "0.1253729     09863637    02937382      029828020"

Quero retirar cada uma  das informações e guardar em um *array*.

obs: estou lendo de arquivo *.txt*.

Comment: As aspas fazem parte do texto?

Comment: É por linha do documento, separar como? Por espaço ou o ponto também faz parte, são somente espaços ou tem TABs? Poderia detalhar mais? As aspas fazem parte do texto?

Answer (score 9):

Use a função split do Java.

Como parâmetro da função split, você passa o separador que no caso é o espaço.

```
String foo = "Palavra1 Palavra2 Palavra3";
String[] split = foo.split(" ");
split[0] = "Palavra1";
split[1] = "Palavra2";
split[2] = "Palavra3";
```

Answer (score 7):

Dessa forma aqui também funciona, utilizando regex e `Stream`:

```
String str = "0.1253729 09863637 02937382 029828020";

String[] array = Pattern.compile("\\s+")//regex que filtra um ou mais espaços
                               .splitAsStream(str)//quebra a string em um array de Stream
                               .toArray(String[]::new);//converte num array de String
```

Veja [funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/vnGF9u).

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi você quer quebrar a *string* no " ", que seria o intervalo.

Pode usar a função split:

```
String[] strRetorno = "0.1253729 09863637 02937382 029828020".split(" ");
```